# c++ 11 std::thread use ofstream output stuff, but get nothing, why?

Tags: c++, multithreading

What would happen after running these code below?

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void func()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    ofstream outfile("test.txt");
    outfile << "hello world" << endl;
    outfile.close();
}

void start()
{
    std::thread th(std::bind(func));
    if (th.joinable())
        th.detach();
}

int main()
{
    start();
    return 0;
}
```

Result is that "test.txt" file will not be created in the disk. why?

In addition, are there problems if I use the heap data which new in start() function in the func()? The os will delete it when the main thread return but the child thread still running?

Comment: You create a thread and your program terminates before the thread is even ran.. Thus nothing is executed. If your thread happened to launch, you detach it and terminate your program.. Your thread dies prematurely. In every case, something bad happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Brandon has pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500616/c-11-stdthread-use-ofstream-output-stuff-but-get-nothing-why#comment68244939_40500616), your thread very likely doesn't get a chance to run. `main()` calls `start()` which constructs the thread, then returns back to `main()` which then exits. Even *if* your thread got a chance to run in that time, you put a 5s sleep in there.

You need to wait for your thread to finish before terminating the program. You can use [`std::thread::join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) for this:

```
void start()
{
    std::thread th(std::bind(func));
    // if the thread was successfully created
    if (th.joinable())
        // wait for it to finish
        th.join();
}
```

You could also consider [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) if you didn't need to wait entirely on your thread, and your thread could alert you when some of its work is done.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the thread will still running when the main thread is return because of the th.detach()...